# What is the time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

```
count = 0
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i*=2){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        count++
    }
}
```

What will be the time complexity of the above code?

With my calculation, it will be log base 2 n.

Please help me with it

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop will do the following number of iterations:

1
        2
        4
        8
        ...
        ~

...where each line represents one iteration of the outer loop.

The total number of times that the body of the inner loop runs is therefore:

2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + 2<sup>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub></sup>

This is equal to:

2<sup>1+log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub></sup> − 1 = 2 − 1

...which is O()

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it